# Would removing all nitrogen from the air cause altitude sickness effects?

Tags: ideal-gas, inert-gases

The total pressure in the lungs is close to the external pressure of 101kPa, i.e. breathing requires little delta-P.

The removal of all nitrogen in the air would not change the 20kPa partial pressure of oxygen. However, lung tissue at 37C also has 6kPa of water vapour pressure and we breathe out about 5kPa of carbon dioxide.

One would think well ventilated lungs very roughly have 90kPa of air in them (the other 11kPa taken up by water and CO2), or up to 18kPa O2. But removal of all nitrogen would leave lungs with only 20kPa total pressure, which means only 9kPa of oxygen. This "11 kPa deadspace rule" predicts an oxygen only atmosphere is equivalent to 60 kPa of air, which is over 4000 meters altitude.

So would removal of nitrogen (assuming it was just slow enough to prevent decompression sickness) cause altitude effects in humans? It would be ironic to have explosive fires (more sensitive to oxygen *percentage* than partial pressure) while humans are gasping for breath.